# Can a string be called into a web browser?

Tags: vb.net

I have a string that contains a slew of text that I'm returning from the server.

***I wanted to know if that string can be called on the client-side?***

What I did was reader a text file to a string
Placed the string into a rich text box
created a sub routine and declared a variable "X" to equal the rich textbox
and finally called the sub into the web browser but I don't get anything called when I call the sub.

What am I doing wrong here folks?

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fileContents As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each f As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\cbu05\Desktop\Tester").GetFiles("*.txt")

        ' Specify a file pattern here     
        fileContents.Append(File.ReadAllText(f.FullName) & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    ' Now you can access all the contents using fileContents.ToString() 

    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & fileContents.ToString()

    WebBrowser1.Navigate(textbox1.text)


End Sub
 '=====================================================================

Sub submaker()

    Dim maker As String = RichTextBox1.Text


End Sub
'=============================================================================
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Call submaker()

End Sub
'==========================================================================

End Class
```

Sorry guys for the limited information. Here is exactly what I am trying to do... I am trying to code my application to navigate to a website (my own) and fill a web form.

The only way that I know to do this using the web browser is to have the information in the document_completed section of the browser. This works great but once I compile the code and setup my application I don't have any way to update my application with new websites.

What I was trying to do is go ahead and code my web browser document_completed with about 5 of my websites. I would need to have the ability to update my application with new sites and the only way I could do this was to create an update and patch my current .exe of the application.

My work around was to try to create a generic sub routine, in the sub routine I would tell the application to navigate to a folder, read each text file in a folder (which would contain the document_completed code for the webbrowser) and then put the code into a string...finally I would call the sub into the webbrowser.

The thinking behind this would that I could add/remove website by just adding/removing the txt files in the folder.

Comment: What does this string contain?  What do you want to happen when you "call" your string?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, strings can be "called" (evaluated) using the `eval` method.  It's controversial and there are probably other ways to do what you're trying to do, but you've opened Pandora's box.  Here's more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1):

As Brian L. points out, strings in JavaScript can be passed to the `eval` method and the interpreter will treat that string as JavaScript code, executing it. Unfortunately the string you're showing is not JavaScript, and therefore the interpreter would fail to understand it and fail due to a syntax error after the first word.

Also, just at a glance, the code you've posted seems to do something that JavaScript on the client side can't do, namely file IO. Can you give more details about what you're trying to do exactly and what code you want to execute on the client side?

Comment: Well said Peter, @Roger you might want to post something more about the vb.net (?) code you're using so that any JS developers who aren't familiar can better understand your question.